# Prove inequality for $xyz=1$

Tags: inequality

I am having trouble to prove an intermediate step $(xy+xz+yz)^2 \geq 3xyz(x+y+z)$ for $x,y,z\geq0$.

Comment: Try multiplying $(xy + xz + yz)$ with $(xy + xz + yz)$ and seeing what common factors you can remove from all terms.

Comment: If you expand it becomes $(xy)^2+(yz)^2+(zx)^2\ge (xy)(zx)+(yz)(xy)+(zx)(yz)$ which is immediate from the rearrangement inequality. Note that you do not need $x,y,z\ge0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(xz + yz + xy)^2-3xyz(x+y+z) = \sum_{cyc}x^2y^2-\sum_{cyc}x^2yz \geq 0 $$
by [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) or [Newton's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities).

Comment: how do cyc and sym equate?

Comment: @kantorovich: it is quite trivial that here $\sum_{cyc}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}$ in both cases.

Comment: Or simply by the inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ (simple to prove, e.g. see the ending of clark's answer), where in this case you can let $a=xy$, $b=yz$, $c=zx$.

Answer (score 2):

Using that $xyz=1$ we see that the inequality we want to prove is equivalent
to
$$(1/x + 1/y+1/z)^2 \geq 3xyz(x+y+z) \fbox {1}  $$

Set $x=1/x,y=1/y,z=1/z$, and notice that the restraint for the new variables stays the same i.e. $xyz=1$ again.

Now we substitube to  $\fbox{1}  $ and get$$ (  x+y+z  )^2\geq 3xyz(1/x+1/y+1/z)$$

So,
 $$ (  x+y+z  )^2\geq 3xy+3yz+3zx$$

By expanding and canceling and multiplying by 2 we get

$$2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \geq 2(xy+yz+zx)$$
But now by bringing everything to the left side and factoring we get
$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2\geq 0$$
And we condlude.